# Load base64 encoded field

Tags: load, base64, blob, crm, qliksense

I'm reading a database from Microsoft CRM. That works fine. I need to read the notes field from the database (annotationbase). Like in this screenshot:

[Notes MS CRM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QKy4.png)

My code for loading the information I need:

```
LIB CONNECT TO 'CRM';
LOAD someuninterestingfield1,
    someuninterestingfield2,
    someuninterestingfield3,
    someuninterestingfield4,
    someuninterestingfield5,
    someuninterestingfield6,
    BASE64ENCODEDFIELDINEED;
SQL SELECT someuninterestingfield1,
    someuninterestingfield2,
    someuninterestingfield3,
    someuninterestingfield4,
    someuninterestingfield5,
    someuninterestingfield6,
    BASE64ENCODEDFIELDINEED
FROM "CRM_DATABASE".usr.AnnotationBase;
```

BASE64ENCODEDFIELDINEED has a base64 encoded xml-file I need for my analysis.
I have no idea (I couldn't find anything about decoding data while or after loading in Qlik Sense) how to decode the content to finally receive my xml-data.
I'm using Qlik Sense 3.0 and MS CRM 2015 (on premise).

Can someone help me?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
Casts are the right direction, but not the way James Wood said.

SQL-Helps you a lot with the Cast functions, the problem is that you need to cast the cast (to binary and then to char):

```
SQL SELECT CAST( CAST( "BASE64ENCODEDFIELDINEED" as XML ).value('.','varbinary(max)') AS varchar(max) ) as decodedField
```

Another part of my project was, to interpret the decodedField as an XML-File. There's a function in Qlik Sense which is called From_Field (+ Load of course) and using the xmlsimple from Qlik parses you the result:

```
LOAD * From_Field(<TABLEYOUNEEDTOLOADFROM>, decodedField)(xmlsimple, table is [<TABLEINYOURXMLFILE>]);
```

I hope this will be helpful for someone with the exact same problem, because I think there aren't as much Qlik Sense developers in here as you might think.

Best greetings

Answer (score 0):

You just need to decode the Base64 string.

A [quick](https://kieronvella.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/functions-to-encode-decode-from-string-to-base64-and-vice-versa-in-mssql-t-sql/) [search](http://www.jrevell.com/base64-encoding-and-decoding-with-sql-server-unicode-characters/) in Google [suggests](http://blog.falafel.com/t-sql-easy-base64-encoding-and-decoding/) TSQL it would look like this:

```
cast(” as xml).value(‘xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@source"))’, ‘varchar(max)’)
```

Whilst apparently [QilkSense](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-3359) has built in functions for this such as `utility.custom_decrypt`or `byte.decode(base64_encoded_private_key)`.

Comment: You did not read your own source:
"Using the QlikView " .... I'm using qliksense. You can't use casts or this function in a load-statement... But thanks for your help. I already found these posts and they couldn't help me.